# How to deactivate an item of the context-menu (Mozilla addon-kit)

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, contextmenu

I would like to deactivate all top-level `context-menu`-items of my addon under certain circumstances (for example when the addon has been disabled by the user).
Somehow I can't figure out how this is done except for completely destroying the item; but I'd prefer using a method that allows easy switching between deactivation and activation.
There must be some way around the missing of an remove- or deactivate-method. For items that are not on top-level but belong to a submenu this is easyly done with the methods `addItem()` and `removeItem()` of the `parentMenu`.

---

EDIT:
Items on top-level do have the property `parentMenu`- which is `null` though. So the problem seems to be that the context-menu.js only offers removeItem/addItem methods for the submenus but not for the parentNode of top-level items.

---

I still find the `context-menu`-api kind of confusing. There is no onClick method for the item. It seems to me that I need a content script for every item, instead(?)
Also, I havent found a way to place items on top-level where I want (instead of being forced to the bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upcoming changes in the SDK's context-menu module due to ship at the end of the month should allow you to use addItem()/removeItem(). This re-written implementation of the context-menu module will ship in SDK 1.13. Currently there is no way to 'deactivate' an item programmatically until this new version is available.